# Why the definition of functions are separated from declarations?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Why the definition of functions is not written in the same "some.h" file together with their declarations? What will be happen if we are not separate "some.h" file from "some.c" file?

Comment: You would have "multiple definition" errors when you attempt to link multiple translation units that all include the header.

Comment: Thanks for asking this, I always wondered about that. Our teacher didn't explain the need for this. @Kerrek why not make the functions implicitly inline by the compiler then?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Historical? Handling inline definitions is more complicated and demanding to implement, so no need to require it from your C89 compiler...

Answer (score 1):

So that one knows the minimum he needs to know. (This makes the compilation faster, chances of name collisions lesser, ability to manage code easier etc) As mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932839/why-the-definition-of-functions-are-separated-from-declarations#comment61425366_36932839) by Kerrek SB: If you mix source and code, dividing big projects into modules is difficult.

For example, you can compile a library (Containing definition) and give it to your clients (who care only about the interface) along with the declarations (Headers) and he would be able to use it without needing to know the source of implementation. (This way you can also hide the implementation detail)

Without headers, he doesn't know usage of functions available in library. So though not mandatory, it is recommended to keep the declaration and definitions separate.

Comment: I.e it is just for writing a clear code? but from the compiler of view it doesn't matter they are separated or not?

Comment: @DavidTsaturyan It does. A well managed project compiles faster.

Answer (score 0):

Well in fact, separating declarations and definitions is not mandatory, while in practice everything was thought this way to separate usage and implementation, this to promote abstraction, reusability, modularity, etc.

If you don't follow these rules then you will very rapidly face compilation problems with multiple definitions, etc.